# Adding fields dynamically using JavaScript makes fields disappear

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

This is my JS code :

```
<script language="javascript">
function addInput() {
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "<input type='text' value='' name='a1[]' size='60' />";
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "<input type='text' value='' name='a2[]' size='9' /><br />";
}

function addInput1() {
    document.getElementById('text1').innerHTML += "<input type='text' value='' name='b[]' size='30' /><br />";
}

function addInput2() {
    document.getElementById('text2').innerHTML += "<input type='text' value='' name='c[]' size='30' />
}
</script>
```

This is my PHP form codes :

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" >


<input type="submit" onclick="addInput()" name="add" value="Add Other" />
<div id="text"></div>

<input type="submit" onclick="addInput1()" name="add1" value="Add Other" />
<div id="text1"></div>

<input type="submit" onclick="addInput2()" name="add2" value="Add Other" />
<div id="text2"></div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

When I add the fields, it works perfectly, but when I try to edit the field, the page resets and all the added fields disappear.

Are there any problems with my JS code? Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Off topic, but `elem.innerHTML += "...new content..."` is very destructive. While there may be some cases where it doesn't make much difference, I would suggest avoiding this practice. In your case, it'll erase the values of the inputs that are being destroyed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using submit buttons to add inputs, but submit buttons submits the form better to use button inputs e.g.

```
<input type="button">
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer :D. Didn't thought it would be very simple. :D . Really appreciate your help :D

Answer (score 0):

Submits buttons are for submitting the form. It's better to use buttons, but also returning `false` will stop default behaviour of the button. Ex:

```
function addInput() {
  // your code
  return false;
}
```

and on the html:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return addInput()" name="add" value="Add Other" />
```